# how do I clear the contents of qtextbrowser in pyqt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

How can I clear the content of `QTextBrowser` ?
I have tried clearHistory() as well as setting the cursor opstion but didint help

does anyone know how to clear the content of the Qtextbrowser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`QTextBrowser`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html) inherits from [`QTextEdit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) so its methods also inherit it, considering the above a [`QTextEdit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) clear the contents with the [`clear()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#clear) method so it also works for [`QTextBrowser`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html): `self.textBrowser.clear()`.

<sub>**Recommendation**: You should read the Qt docs to know all the methods of each class, for example from QTextBrowser https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser-members.html</sub>